# Linearize cards in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code to show my layout, I have tried many combinations but with none I can align them:

```
 <div class="col col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="card-columns">
            @foreach($asesorias as $asesoria)
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;height:100%">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="/adminlte/img/user4-128x128.jpg" alt="Foto perfil asesor">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $asesoria->place }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <strong>Comunidad: </strong>{{ $asesoria->comunidad_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Provincia: </strong>{{ $asesoria->provincia_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Municipio:</strong>{{ $asesoria->municipio_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Lugar: </strong>{{ $asesoria->place }}<br>
                        <strong>Fecha: </strong>{{ $asesoria->date }}<br>
                        <strong>Hora: </strong>{{ $asesoria->time }}<br>
                        <br>
                    </p>

                </div>
                <div class="text-center"
                    style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left:0;right:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reservar</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

but the result view is this:

[image: cards]

Cards are not align because content is diferent in each one.

```
.card-columns {
    column-count:3;
 }
```

How could I linearize them?

I have changed by

> card-deck

but now I ask me, if I want only 4 columns in my view, how doing it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your `card`'s in `card-deck` groups. This way it is not necessary to declare how many elements are in each group. If, i.e you want three elements in each group you can do it this way:

```
<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card>...</div>
    <div class="card>...</div>
    <div class="card>...</div>
</div>
```

In case you want a second row, just add another `card-deck` with other three elements.

This way all the elements in each group will be perfectly aligned.

I also recommend you to use the `card-body`, `card-text` and `card-footer` tags. You can check its usage [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#header-and-footer).

Answer (score 0):

The `card-columns` class is by default a masonry view. For even rows, you'll want to change the `card-columns` class to multiple `card-deck` divs.

See documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-decks

Comment: I edited my question. I don't underand how could see only 4 columns centered in my view?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code for 4 columns.

```
<div class="col-12">
        @foreach($asesorias as $asesoria)
            @if($loop->index % 4 == 0)
                <div class="card-deck">
            @endif
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img src="/adminlte/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $asesoria->place }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <strong>Comunidad: </strong>{{ $asesoria->comunidad_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Provincia: </strong>{{ $asesoria->provincia_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Municipio:</strong>{{ $asesoria->municipio_id }}<br>
                        <strong>Lugar: </strong>{{ $asesoria->place }}<br>
                        <strong>Fecha: </strong>{{ $asesoria->date }}<br>
                        <strong>Hora: </strong>{{ $asesoria->time }}<br>
                        <br></p>
                    <p class="card-text text-center" style="position:absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Reservar</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if($loop->iteration % 4 == 0)
                </div>
            @endif

        @endforeach

    </div>
```